# How to create recursive type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have elements which have sub-elements that are structured the same as their parent. When I create types of them using TypeScript, I am having some errors. How can I solve that issue?

```
type RowRecord = Record<string, CellData>;
type CellData = string | number | RowRecord;
```

**Errors:**

- Type alias 'CellData' circularly references itself.
- Type alias 'RowRecord' circularly references itself.

**Example record:**

```json
{
    "id": "60f49dbb3ee1a9241749abb6",
    "gender": "female",
    "firstName": "Millicent",
    "lastName": "Harrington",
    "birthDate": "2013-05-14T04:35:49.400Z",
    "age": 8,
    "email": "millicent@harrington.com",
    "address": {
      "country": "USA",
      "state": "Utah",
      "city": "Cecilia",
      "street": "Newkirk Placez",
      "houseNumber": 969
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do by expanding `Record` to the object it represents

```
type RowRecord = { [K in string]: CellData }; // or { [k: string]: CellData }
type CellData = string | number | RowRecord;
```

TypeScript doesn't allow your definition because `Record<string, CellData>` is eagerly evaluated. If you give TS an object type, then TypeScript recognizes that it can defer the evaluation of that type, permitting a recursive definition.

Comment: I have tried your solution and it worked. But I don't know about such "{ [k: string]: CellData }" data structure. Could you tell me what is this or recommend me any source about it?

Comment: `[k: string]` there is an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), `[k in string]` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)