Able to use interface as generic before interface is declared
Why does this work? I would expect SomeInterface to not be defined in time to be passed as an argument:
interface SomeInterface
  extends Model<
    InferAttributes<SomeInterface>,
    InferCreationAttributes<SomeInterface>
  >
{ ...

(example from https://sequelize.org/api/v7/types/_sequelize_core.index.inferattributes)

TS allows recursive type definitions (otherwise interface Foo { x(): Foo } would be invalid and that’s bad news for things like Array with methods that return arrays). The real question is exactly how it is recursive, because not all recursive types are allowed (type Bar = string | Bar is illegal, for example). That means ideally you’d provide definitions for your other types directly here in the question for it to be a [mre]. What is Model?

(See prev comment) I suppose that’s some sequelize thing, right? So then the tag on the question and the link is probably sufficient for this to be a [mre]. Still, if you don’t get enough engagement here you might want to remove the dependency on sequelize, especially if your question is not actually about sequelize. Good luck!

@jcalz I see, you helped me find the name for it is circular types or recursive types. That is all I needed, thanks!

So what should we do with this question? Answer it? Remove it? Point to some existing q/a about recursive types?

I like this explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70405610/5570385 not exactly the same bc its types instead of interfaces but close enough to help other users get somewhere from an explanation of recursive types (in question)
